# jQuery Mobile: Swipeleft/Swiperight is jumping itself

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, jquery-mobile, swipe

i use this code to react on the swipeleft/swiperight event:

```
$('body').live('pagecreate', function(event) {
    $('div[data-role="page"]').live("swipeleft", function() {
        var nextpage = $(this).next('div[data-role="page"]');
        // swipe using id of next page if exists
        if (nextpage.length > 0) {
            $.mobile.changePage(nextpage);
        }
    });
    $('div[data-role="page"]').live("swiperight", function() {
        var prevpage = $(this).prev('div[data-role="page"]');
        // swipe using id of previous page if exists
        if (prevpage.length > 0) {
            $.mobile.changePage(prevpage, {
                reverse : true,
            });
        }
    });
});
```

It works, but after about 3 swipes (maybe when i reach the end of the 4 pages) there´s no normal behaviour anymore. For example: I swipe left --> i get the nextpage but then it swipes back and then again (i reach the expected page but not in that case i want). That happens after about 3 swipes all the time. What´s wrong with the code?

Thx a lot!

Answer (score 5):

You know there is a plugin from the JQM devs just for that: [JQM pagination](http://filamentgroup.com/lab/jquery_mobile_pagination_plugin/)

I think your problem is related to multiple bindings.

Put a `console.log` in every binding to see how often it fires. Like so:

```
$('body').live('pagecreate', function(event) {
console.log( "PAGECREATE fired")
$('div[data-role="page"]').live("swipeleft", function() {
    console.log("binding to swipe-left on "+$(this).attr('id') );
    var nextpage = $(this).next('div[data-role="page"]');
    // swipe using id of next page if exists
    if (nextpage.length > 0) {
        $.mobile.changePage(nextpage);
    }
});
$('div[data-role="page"]').live("swiperight", function() {
    console.log("binding to swipe-right "+$(this).attr('id');
    var prevpage = $(this).prev('div[data-role="page"]');
    // swipe using id of previous page if exists
    if (prevpage.length > 0) {
        $.mobile.changePage(prevpage, {
            reverse : true,
        });
    }
});
});
```

If these fire more than once, you will attach multiple bindings to your pages, which will `all` trigger `changePage` on swipe, when you only want `one` event to fire with every swipe.

**EDIT:**
First up, if you are using latest Jquery you should bind using `on/off` and not use `live` anymore.
One way would be to `unbind` on `pagehide` and re-`bind` when the page is reloaded. I guess that would be recommended way. However if you are not removing the page from the DOM when swiping to the next page, you will unbind and since `pagecreate` will not fire again (page still in the DOM, no need to create), you will not `bind` again when you swipe back.

I'm also dealing with this a lot and am using this:

```
$(document).on('pageshow', 'div:jqmData(role="page")', function(){

     var page = $(this), nextpage, prevpage;

     // check if the page being shown already has a binding
      if ( page.jqmData('bound') != true ){
            // if not, set blocker
            page.jqmData('bound', true)
            // bind
                .on('swipeleft.paginate', function() {
                    console.log("binding to swipe-left on "+page.attr('id') );
                    nextpage = page.next('div[data-role="page"]');
                    if (nextpage.length > 0) {
                        $.mobile.changePage(nextpage);
                        }
                    })
                .on('swiperight.paginate', function(){
                    console.log("binding to swipe-right "+page.attr('id');
                    prevpage = page.prev('div[data-role="page"]');
                    if (prevpage.length > 0) {
                        $.mobile.changePage(prevpage, {
                            reverse : true,
                            });
                        };
                     });
            }
        });
```

This will fire with every `pageshow` and check if the page is `bound`. If not, it sets the bindings on this page. The next time `pageshow` fires `bound` will be true, so it will not re-bind. If the page is removed from the DOM and reloaded, `bound` will not be set and the binding will be reset.

I have also added `.paginate` to your swipeleft/swiperight so you could remove them all at once using `off`

Comment: Yeah there are more than once bindings. But how can i reduce them, or in better words: Where´s the error in this code, because it looks very normal.